# How can I develop pure GUI wxwigets program by XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, wxwidgets

I have create a wxwidgets program(Pure C++) , the build is success and running is OK

But when I click the program in finder, a terminal windows is popup.

How to avoid the terminal window being popup?

PS: Similiar problem is also seen in Visual Studio, and can be fixed by changing subsystem from Console to Windows

Is there a similiar configuration in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make a bundle for your application under OS X. If you use Xcode, this should already be the case. If you use makefiles/command line, look at how the minimal sample included in wxWidgets distribution does it.